# CSS for views asp.net core

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to stlye my .net core website. Currently there is a file called site.css with all the css for the website. However since i have multiple views i would like to be able to pick and choose what css is applied to what view. I want all my views to have the same navbar as my homepage or index view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> However since i have multiple views i would like to be able to pick and choose what css is applied to what view.

You can add a `Render Section` control to your layout.

In your _layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("css", required: false) <-- Add this
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And in your view file, you can specify which css it depends on:

```
@section css{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some-css.css" />
}
```

> I want all my views to have the same navbar as my homepage or index view. Any suggestions?

Simply put the navbar in your layout view file is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Your Solution caused the effect but the Desrired output is not as estimated.  Upvoted you. Thanks. Will do more study on MVC5 CSS `@section`

Answer (score 0):

Apply all your css changes to shared/_layout.cshtml page.

[Document Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-4-layout-and-section-in-razor/)